# how to call an element in another layer hbs

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

There are two hbs files, one is under another layer, for example:

`testA.hbs` contains,

```
<div>
  {{/testB.hbs}} 
</div> 
<div id="area">
  Hello, world 
</div>
```

At `testB.js`, I want to call the id `area` which is presented at `testA.hbs`. How can I achieve this?

Comment: could you make a demonstration of what you want with ember-twiddle.com since it's not super clear to me what you want?

Comment: do you find my answer helpful? If so please verify it or comment if you still need any clarifications.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my understanding on what you need, you want to pass the property `id` from one template `test-a` to another template `test-b`.

So in order to make a property `id` available to your template `test-b`, you must pass it in like this `{{test-b id="area"}}`

Now you can access the property `id` in your

`test-b.hbs` as `{{id}}`

`test-b.js` as `this.get('id')`

Have a look at my [ember-twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/#/08e42f3263fcc90503ffb19056055e0d) for a working example. Replicated the same scenario with two components.

Comment: I like the approach you did at your ember-twiddle.